# Showing that $|\text{Hom}_\mathbb{Q}(K,K)|=6$

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory

Let $g\in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ be irreducible with $\text{deg}\;g=3$. We assume that only one of the roots of $g$ is in $\mathbb{R}$. So, $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.
Let $L\subset\mathbb{C}$ be the splitting field of $g$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Show that for every homomorphism $\tau: \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)\rightarrow L$ there are exactly two homomorphisms $\pi,\pi': L \rightarrow L$ such that $\pi,\pi'|_{\mathbb{Q}}=\tau$. Then infer that $|\text{Hom}_\mathbb{Q}(L,L)|=6$.

---

The way I see it, the situation is as follows:

$\mathbb{Q}\subset \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)\subset \mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta)\subset \mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta,\bar{\beta})=L$

$\mathbb{Q}\subset \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)\subset \mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\bar{\beta})\subset \mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta,\bar{\beta})=L$

By theorem there exist unique homomorphisms $\pi_{\beta,\bar{\beta}}:L=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\bar{\beta})(\beta) \rightarrow L$ with $\pi_{\beta,\bar{\beta}}(\beta)=\bar{\beta}$ and $\pi'_{\beta,\beta}:L=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\bar{\beta})(\beta) \rightarrow L$ with $\pi'_{\beta,\beta}(\beta)=\beta$, where $\beta,\bar{\beta}\in\mathbb{C}$ are the complex roots of $g$.

By corollary of the prior used theorem there is a bijection between $\text{Hom}_\mathbb{Q}(\mathbb{Q}(\alpha),L)$ and the set of all roots of $g$ in $L$.
Since there are three roots, it follows that $\text{Hom}_\mathbb{Q}(\mathbb{Q}(\alpha),L)=3$. Also, since each one of these can be continued by $\pi_{\beta,\bar{\beta}}$ and $\pi'_{\beta,\beta}$, we have $|\text{Hom}_\mathbb{Q}(L,L)|=6$.

---

Hmm, I just realized, I need more homomorphisms for when $\tau$ sends $\alpha$ to $\beta$ or $\bar{\beta}$.

---

What do you think? Does this work at all?

Comment: Consider complex conjugation as a $\Bbb{Q}$-automorphism of $L$. Also, note that $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta,\bar{\beta})=\Bbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta)$, which can save you some writing.